# Yii CDbCriteria select row based on count of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, yii, count

I have a posts table and a users table. Posts are linked to Users using an authorId column in posts table. I want to select those users with at least one or more posts using CDbCriteria for a CGridView.
Below is the sql query that I am trying to implement.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM user 
    WHERE ID IN 
        (SELECT creatorId FROM video GROUP BY creatorId HAVING count(*) > 0)
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('videoCount');

$criteria->addCondition('t.status=1');
$criteria->addCondition('videoCount>0');
```

This doesn't work because the 'videoCount' is a relation.

How do I accomplish this? I am using Yii 1.1.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using the query builder** if you could as it will be much easy

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                        ->select()
                        ->from('user')
                        ->where(array('in','ID',  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                                                            ->select('creatorId')
                                                            ->from('video')
                                                            ->group('creatorId')
                                                            ->having('count(*) > 0')->queryColumn()))
                   ->queryAll();
```

**This will execute the required query** i.e

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `ID` IN ('SELECT `creatorId` FROM `video` GROUP BY `creatorId` HAVING count(*) > 0')
```

**Update**

If you want to stick with **CDbCriteria** then you can try this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('ID IN (SELECT creatorId FROM video GROUP BY creatorId HAVING count(*) > 0)');
```

**Note:-** I haven't tested this criteria but hopefully it will work.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use this. I want this go through a CActiveDataProvider and then to be used in a CGridView in the view file. Is that possible if I use the query builder?

Comment: You can use the CArrayDataProvider instead of CActiveDataProvider